# NullPointerException JApplet with getClass().getResource

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, japplet

I want to add an image to JPanel in JApplet (so that I could create the jar file), so I used :

```
Image x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
  getClass().getResource("D:/THANH_TAI LIEU/niet/hinhtu.jpg"));
```

but the java.lang.NullPointerException occured. I'm sure the image path is correct, because the applet run fine when I used :

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/THANH_TAI LIEU/niet/hinhtu.jpg"));
```

The exceptions :

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:830)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(SunToolkit.java:887)
at applet$CustomPanel.paintComponent(applet.java:65)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
```

The code:

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import java.awt.Toolkit;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JApplet;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;

  public class applet extends JApplet {
  public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  private void createGUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("CLICK ME");
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.add(new CustomPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel);
    }

public class CustomPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/THANH_TAI LIEU/niet/hinhtu.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("D:/THANH_TAI LIEU/niet/hinhtu.jpg"));
        g.drawImage(x, 0, 0, null); 

    }   



}
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I guess `getClass().getResource(...)` demands relative path with respect to your class file. So depending on that you need to specify, where you image is located. How come your `Toolkit` will know where is `Drive D`. Check this link for further help : [How to add images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659).

Comment: Yeah, the problem solved. I put the pic into the same path with the class file, and getResource("/hinhtu.jpg")); - it worked!!

Comment: That code still has some problems, even if the resource is found. 1) Trying to load 2 images in `paintComponent()` - never load resources in that method. 2) Using `null` as the `ImageObserver` for the drawing, when `this` (the `JPanel`) **is an** `ImageObserver`.  -- Is it intended to add any components on top of `CustomPanel`, or to draw anything else to it?  If not, just put the image in a label and add it to the CENTER of the parent panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass().getResource()`
Works only for the class path of the project.
You need to put the image file on the class path in order to find
Where  `ImageIO.read()` can read whatever is passed in the params as input stream.